# How to store data related to members of groups in a forum, using Cassandra?

Tags: database, nosql, cassandra

Hii there,

My question is related to Groups in a forum, very much similar to the LinkedIn Groups.

How would you store the list of all users in a group in a discussion forum?...and when the size of groups are quite large like in tens of thousands members in a group ?

Also how can you find the mutual connections of the user in that group ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest doing this as one row per group, with a column for each member of the group.  This will work well for any number of users in the group.

Regarding finding "mutual connections", the simplest way to handle this is to scan through the second user's connections and compare the two.

Here's an alternate strategy: assume that we want to find all of the mutual connections for user 'A' in group 'G'.  If the columns in the A's connection row use the connections' usernames (or user ids) as the the column names, you can do (in [pycassa](https://github.com/pycassa/pycassa) syntax):

```
group_members = GROUPS.get('G').keys()
group_members.remove('A')
user_connections = USERS.get('A').keys()
mutual_connections = USERS.multiget(group_members, columns=connections)
```

Basically, this will go to a row for each user in the group and pull out only the columns that correspond to the original user's connections.  This will move the work from the client to Cassandra, but it's hard to tell how much extra work this would be for Cassandra without a performance test.

Comment: Thanks Tyler! 
(1.) Wont a single row for storing all the members as column names would be too large because at a time only a few members are required to be displayed. and sometimes if the no of members become even higher like in 6 digits then wont that lead to performance issues? Yes, I have heard that it is possible to store millions of columns in a single row but does it really mean that it has no negative impact on the cassandra performance?

Comment: ( 2.) Do you mean something like this for mutual connection calculations:- 
First find all connections of the user as UserIds-> Then find all the columns with those names, in the row of the group. -> So whatever columns you, get is the mutual connections, right ?
So if some column name existed in user connection row and, when you asked for a column with the same name in the group's row and if it existed then you get a mutual connection &  if it did not existed you get nothing. Can cassandra silently ignore all the column names that were asked for but they did not existed in that row?

Comment: (1) Storing millions of columns in a row only becomes a performance issue if you expect to read the row entirely, frequently, and quickly (without some good caching); even then, it may not be a problem. You can very efficiently pull the first or last N columns from a row.

Comment: (2) Yes, Cassandra will silently ignore columns that you ask for that do not exist in a row (efficiently, too, due to a bloom filter). I think you have the correct idea.  You are finding the intersection of user A's friends and, for each user X in the group besides A, user X's friends.

Comment: Thanks so much Tyler!! I am trying to find the intersection by asking for column without caring about whether they exist or not in the row!